# FormatMessage без переносов на новую строку

Tags: c++, winapi

Я получаю сообщение об ошибке полученной через `GetLastError`, и использую `FormatMessage` для преобразования в читабельный вид (*для отладки*).

```
std::string get_last_error_std_string(const DWORD error_code)
{
    const DWORD fmt_message_flags =
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS;

    const DWORD lng_id = MAKELANGID(LANG_RUSSIAN, SUBLANG_RUSSIAN_RUSSIA);

    std::string result;

    if (error_code)
    {
        LPVOID msg_buf = nullptr;

        const DWORD buf_len = FormatMessage
        (
            fmt_message_flags,
            nullptr,
            error_code,
            lng_id,
            reinterpret_cast<LPWSTR>(&msg_buf),
            0,
            nullptr
        );

        if (buf_len)
        {
            const int required_memory = WideCharToMultiByte
            (
                CP_UTF8,
                0,
                static_cast<LPCWCH>(msg_buf),
                -1,
                nullptr,
                0,
                nullptr,
                nullptr
            );

            result.resize(required_memory);

            (void)WideCharToMultiByte
            (
                CP_UTF8,
                0,
                static_cast<LPCWCH>(msg_buf),
                static_cast<int>(buf_len),
                &result[0],
                required_memory,
                nullptr,
                nullptr
            );

            LocalFree(msg_buf);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Но данная функция заполняет буфер строки с переносами на новую строку, т.е. в конце имеется 2 символа `\r\n`, которые мне не нужны, т.к. использую форматирование, но за счет того что есть эти символы, у меня ломается вывод в консоль, и вместо запланированного сообщения я вижу лишь его часть:

> Не удалось зарегистрировать класс окна т.к. функция `RegisterClassExW`
>   вернула ошибку 0x57 Ошибка: "Параметр задан неверно.

Но форматирование строки должно было содержать в себе номер строки и файл в котором была получена ошибка:

```
throw std::runtime_error(u8"{0}{1:#x} Ошибка: \"{2}\"{5}Файл: {3}{5}Строка: {4}"_format
(
　　　　u8"Не удалось зарегистрировать класс окна т.к. функция `RegisterClassExW` вернула ошибку ",
　　　　error_code,
　　　　get_last_error_std_string(error_code),
　　　　__FILE__,
　　　　__LINE__ - 2,
　　　　"\n"
));
```

Можно ли без среза строки получить ошибку без переносов на новую строку `\r\n`?

Comment: Непонятно, с чего вдруг будет ломаться вывод в консоль из-за `\r\n`. Вот из-за лишнего `\0` - еще может быть. А если они и мешают, то в чем проблема убрать их из строки?

Comment: `fmt_message_flags |= FORMAT_MESSAGE_MAX_WIDTH_MASK;`

Comment: @VTT: Я думаю это связано с библиотекой `fmt`. Но увы, ничего другого пока мне в голову не пришло как только срезать `\r\n`.